# How to get only List of specific field from List of objects using $push without using $group

Tags: json, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a list of objects in mongoDB

> [{ "name":"Joy", "age":23 }, { "name":"Nick", "age":26 }, {
>   "name":"Merry", "age":27 }, { "name":"Ben", "age":20 }]

I need a result which should have list of ages like

> ages:[23,26,27,20]

Actually these objects are just for an example. I am using some different objects where I can use $group after that $push to get a result but can we get this result without $group?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. If it just a array list you can use `array.age` to get all the ages. no $push needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "objects" you mean MongoDB documents then you can use the trick with grouping by `null` which will basically merge all your documents into one result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ages: { $push: "$age" }
        } 
    }
])
```

You'll get following result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "ages" : [ 23, 26, 27, 20 ] }
```